# Gulp optimizing practices: Useref on small files, copy larger files

Tags: optimization, gulp

So I've been spending a while optimizing my website (which you can view [here](https://thegenieoftruth.github.io/)) and I'm working on using gulp to optimize things. So far, its been going smoothly, but I've reached a roadblock. A friend told me the following:

- Minimal HTTP requests are good
- File size should be kept to a minimum to allow easier caching (especially for mobile devices)

So I've started using useref to concatenate and then compress the files:

```
<!-- app/index.html -->
<!--build:js js/main.min.js-->
<script src="js/shoop.js"></script>
<script src="js/doop.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild-->
```

which turns into

```
<!-- dist/index.html -->
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
```

Now, everything is fine and peachy, but keep in mind what my friend told me about optimal practices. To keep the files small, to allow caching. So say I had:

```
<sript src = "js/big-ol-library-that-shouldnt-be-concatenated.min.js"></script>
```

And wanted it to simply be copied over to dist, and leave the HTML file like so:

```
<!-- dist/index.html -->
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
<sript src = "js/big-ol-library-that-shouldnt-be-concatenated.min.js"></script>
```

If this is an optimal process, how can I accomplish it with gulp?

Regards, TheGenieOfTruth